# UTF-8 encoding only working in index.html?

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a bit of an odd problem here that I cannot figure out. I have two pages: `index.html` and `index2.html`. The `utf-8` character encoding works fine in `index.html` but it does not work in `index2.html`. For example the following paragraph:

> Ex-Fleet Foxes drummer Josh Tillman struck out on his own (he was already a singer/songwriter in his own right prior to joining Foxes) and rechristened himself professionally as “Father John Misty.”

The quotes around Father John Misty display perfectly in `index.html` but appear as diamonds with a question mark on `index2.html`. Both pages have this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I can even copy and paste the exact same source code from `index.html` into `index2.html` and it still does not work. Is there something I need to place into a .htaccess file? I already checked the permissions on both .html files are they are identical. I'm at a loss as to what else the problem might be.

Comment: Check the headers returned by both pages, for the `Content-Type` header. Also check the encoding on both files.

Comment: Maybe the encoding for the file was set wrong in your editor. Delete the bad file index2.html and than copy your working file index.html to index2.html and check again. In most editors you can see and set the encoding for your file.

Comment: The file itself needs to be saved/set as utf-8. The `<meta>` tag shown in your question lets the browser know what encoding to expect the file to be encoded in - it doesn't affect the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the result shows the *Unicode* replacement character �, that means whatever is reading the document is trying to interpret it as Unicode (usually UTF-8), but encountered a byte sequence which is not valid in that encoding.

In other words: the browser is trying to do the right thing, the document is not actually UTF-8 encoded. Check the settings in your editor.